# What Ark specific settings for Ark extraction?

Tags: kubuntu

Using kubuntu 14.04
What Ark specific settings do I use to extract a Kbackup file (stored on a usb disk).
My original files are stored in /home/bumpy.
Sure wouls appreciate a quick reply - am getting desperate!

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Simply use the ark command line:

```
ark [--extract --extract-to --add --add-to --guess-name] [folder] [files] [archive]  Options]
```

Suppose your file is backup_2014.09.29-19.05.44_1.tar

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
$ ark --extract-to /home/bumpy backup_2014.09.29-19.05.44_1.tar
```

Ark command:

Options:

```
--extract // Open extract dialog, quit when finished 

--extract-to folder archive // Extract archive to folder. Quit when finished. folder will be created if it does not exist. 

--add files // Ask for the name of the archive to add files to. Quit when finished. 

--add-to files archive  // Add files to archive. Quit when finished. archive will be created if it does not exist. 

--guess-name folder archive  //  Used with --extract-to. When specified, archive will be extracted to a subfolder of folder whose name will be the name of archive without the filename extension.
```

Source: http://linux.die.net/man/1/ark